# Builder plugin exception after updating to new intelij IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am using intelij as my IDE for a long time.
today I get notification to update intelij to 2020.1 community version.
I am writing in pure java, and use the plugin to auto create builders in classes (it saves plenty of time).
After the update in the bottom right section, I see a blinking stop sign, and when I open it says

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: org/picocontainer/defaults/DefaultPicoContainer [Plugin: Builder Generator]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.instantiate(ActionManagerImpl.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getActionImpl(ActionManagerImpl.java:527)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:515)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.preloadActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:1504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader.preload(ActionPreloader.java:15)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$null$1(Preloader.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:625)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:570)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$null$2(Preloader.java:75)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:210)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:190)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picocontainer/defaults/DefaultPicoContainer
    at pl.mjedynak.idea.plugins.builder.action.AbstractBuilderAction.<clinit>(AbstractBuilderAction.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.instantiate(ActionManagerImpl.java:190)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picocontainer.defaults.DefaultPicoContainer PluginClassLoader[Builder Generator, 1.1.7] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@256e0ac8
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:115)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 24 more
```

from the upgrade, I can not press alt+shift+b and in is not creating the builder any more
The report exception button not do anything.
is there something I can do to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a third-party plugin, so please find contacts of the author and the bug tracker here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6585-builder-generator